# Is there an equivalent of lambda calculus for object oriented languages?

Tags: programming-languages, lambda-calculus, object-oriented

Lambda calculus serves as a foundation for all sorts of functional languages and its various extensions are compiler targets for languages like Haskell, ML, etc. So what is the equivalent for object oriented languages? Is there a minimal object calculus that serves as the foundation for object oriented languages?

Comment: Perhaps you should start by identifying a calculus that models imperative computations, I'm not familiar with one. If you just mean a type system algebra that meshes with the object concept, I would encourage you to define the characteristics of the OO type system you want to know of an algebra that resembles. Many people find different parts of OO type systems intrinsic to the universal concept of "OO", so identifying your concept of it would help.

Comment: The original lambda calculus is untyped so I'm not talking about types.

Comment: You might also be interested in the question [“Modeling objects as functions”](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/225540/60357). In my answer to that question, I showed how to implement a simple object using only functional parts of JavaScript (== lambda calculus), including things such as inheritance and private fields. After all, objects are just closures. (However, that example does not feature “open recursion” which is e.g. needed for the Strategy Pattern)

Comment: You're not talking about types, but the type system is the defining characteristic of "OO", without the type system you're talking about procedural programming... so which is it? Procedural/imperative programming, or the OO type system? If it's just procedural/imperative then you just want a calculi that models imperative computation to which monadic composition is the best model I'm familiar with, though there are surely others.

Comment: Not really. You can talk about objects as a formal system the same way one talks about lambda terms and substitution without relating it to anything imperative. I just don't know what that is hence the question.

Comment: the object is a part of the type system though, like I said. So if you can describe the "object" concept you refer to it would go a long way in demystifying what kind of formalism you're looking for. Just because you can model OO systems with lambda calculus doesn't stand to reason that is a good formalism. You can also model lambda calculus with OO languages, it's a turing tar pit standpoint. Either you're interested in formalisms that are very similar to the OO type system, or imperative computation, or you're asking about ??

Comment: I don't see why we are talking past each other. A formal description of something does not imply a type system. Maybe what you mean is that any formal system of reasoning might as well be a type system. I don't disagree with that but in my mind those are two separate things. Abstract rewriting systems can be used to model computation but I wouldn't call them a type system.

Comment: I guess the basic is WHILE-programs with operative semantics (i.e. procedural style) but that's not what you want. Small-step and big-step semantics probably come closest in the sense that they are calculi used to describe the behaviour of procedural/OO programs. But I don't think it's the same in the sense that you can't "program" with them.

Comment: See: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18963/is-there-a-theory-abstraction-behind-oop/

Comment: OOP is about messaging mostly more than about types. The Actor model is advanced above mainstream OOP. Try π-calculus as a base.

Answer (score 14):

> So what is the equivalent for object oriented languages?

Lambda calculus.

I mean, there is [Cardelli's](http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/PrimObjImpSIPL.A4.pdf) object calculus (and a handful of derivatives), but in general, there's nothing fancy about object oriented languages that requires a new approach to computation.

It's well known (see [TaPL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262162091) for example) how to extend/encode Records and Mutation (and sub-typing/dispatch) onto/in lambda calculus. The underlying structures don't need to change, even though there are often layers above it that add semantic restriction and make things more usable (member access, implied `this`, object layouts, etc).

Comment: You're effectively making a turing tar pit argument here I think, because lambda calculus can model this it is the model - I don't really agree. Yes it can, but as you mention Cardelli's object calculus is a better derivation to fit. There are others as well, but the more I think about it, the only difference between OO and procedural programming is the type system, so a type algebra may be a better formalism. Given your argument The Actor Model is a better answer because it more easily models an OO system than direct lambda calculus.

Comment: I guess the question sounds more to me like "what is the *closest* formal system to OO programming?" given that there is none that OO is founded on. Lambda calculus is not the *closest* formal system to OO, certainly.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa - I read the question as "All these people use lambda calculus as their formalism when designing/implementing functional programming languages. What do people use for OO languages?". In my experience, people still use lambda calculus for OO languages (if they use anything).

Comment: I don't think they do use anything... The design of OO languages has been influenced, near as I can tell, none at all by formalisms but the opposite is not true, there are formalisms derived to model OO language concepts, and those are worth mentioning.

Answer (score -1):

While not *really* an answer to your specific question, I will suggest that those OO langs that do have lambdas (or specifically do *not*) usually do so for practical reasons. The recent inclusion of lambdas/closures in Java 8 is a case-in-point.

This generated a lot of discussion, even well before Java 8. [There is a dense website dedicated to this specific implementation](http://www.javac.info/) that has a lot of technical and theoretical discussion that might be of interest?

Specifically, check out Bloch's "Controversy" slides.

Comment: this is not what he is referring to with the term "lambda"

Comment: Well, not exactly, but the links I provided speak directly to "objects as functions" in Java, and the challenges and controversy surrounding a portion of the language satisfying the lambda calculus. Some of those links discuss the formal application of the calculus in an OO environment.

Comment: That's fine but my question was more about a minimal formal essence of an object system the same way lambda calculus is the minimal essence of functional languages.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought that a practical example of how some of that theory was applied to a shipping OO language might apply here. Java is bad example, of course, because it is intended to be so practical. I suppose more to the point is how something like Ruby could be formalized...

Comment: Right. Some formal object semantics for ruby would be interesting.

Comment: @davidk01: See [The Ruby Object Model:
Data structure in detail](http://www.atalon.cz/rb-om/ruby-object-model/). Moreover, [my answer](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/40455/29733) to [Is there a theory/abstraction behind OOP?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18963/is-there-a-theory-abstraction-behind-oop) contains a sample picture of Ruby's object model core and links to documents that provide generalization of this core structure.

Comment: @paon Thanks, will definitely take a look.